# Why does the matrix made from as_adjacency_matrix(g) for undirected graphs sometimes show entries which are 2 instead of 0 or 1?

Tags: r, igraph

In `igraph` in R, if we use `as_adjacency_matrix(g)` on an undirected graph `g`, sometimes I see an entry of 2 versus just getting 0 or 1. I am used to only getting 0's or 1's but what does a 2 mean and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: It probably means your graph has multiple edges. Try `igraph::simplify`.

Comment: I think I got what is wrong, I have an edgelist `el` that is not symmetric that I put into an undirected graph using `g <- graph_from_data_frame(el, directed = F)` and then calling `as_adj(g)`. The 2 indicates node and edges that are symmetrically connected, in that they both acknowledge they connect to each other. Is there an option to only report 0 an 1's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as_adj()` returns a matrix where any edges between two edges are *counted*. If you have more than one edge between two vertices, the weighted matrix will contain numbers above one. Compare these two examples:

```
# Single edges give weights of 1
g <- make_empty_graph(directed=F) %>% add_vertices(3) %>% add_edges(c(1,2,2,3,3,1))
plot(g)
( as_adj(g) )

# Multiple links give weights > 1
g <- g %>% add_edges(c(1,2,2,3,2,3))
( as_adj(g) )
plot(g)
```